# Is there a way to debug a transaction, and see the gas used by that tx until any given point of the execution? (Ideally in Truffle)

Tags: gas

I'm trying to figure out where are the big gas spender instructions from my contract, so I'm simulating some transactions in a forked local node using ganache-cli and debugging the tx using Truffle. However, I can only see the total gas spent by a transaction. Ideally I'd like to be able to see how much (cumulative) gas has been spent until any point during execution, are there any tools that allow to do this?

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure but tools from https://tenderly.co could do it. Not sure if they can connect to a local network though.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Eth gas reporter plugin](https://github.com/cgewecke/eth-gas-reporter) for a truffle or you can use the remix plugin for the same to check the gas cost per instruction or function. If you are using hardhat then there is [hardhat gas reporter](https://hardhat.org/plugins/hardhat-gas-reporter.html)